# Bounded quantifier with two "bounds" on one variable.

Tags: notation, first-order-logic

There's a widely used convention in logic to restrict what we're quantifying over at the same time as quantifying a variable, for example "$\forall_{x\subseteq\mathbb{N}}$". Is there a convention for when we want to restrict the variable in two ways, like a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ that also has a specified cardinality? One could use a comma like "$\forall_{x\subseteq\mathbb{N},|x|=3}$", but I'm hesitant to do it because commas are already used to separate different variables. Consider "$\forall_{x\subseteq\mathbb{N},|x|=3, y\in\mathbb{N}}$": the three strings "$x\subseteq\mathbb{N}$","$|x|=3$" and "$y\in\mathbb{N}$" syntatically look like they have the same "status", but in fact the second one doesn't introduce a variable.

Comment: Honestly? If you're not doing formal logic, I'd never write something like that. If you are, I'd write $\forall x \left((x \subset \mathbb{N} \wedge |x| = 3) \Rightarrow ...\right)$, or the equivalent in whatever other formalism you're using.

Comment: @user3482749 that's an option I haven't considered, thanks. However, I don't think I've ever seen the implication thing instead of a bounded quantifier outside of formal logic (admittedly, I haven't seen that many logical formulas) , it makes the formula long and if we add parentheses like you did there will be a lot of them. If we don't add them then I'm not sure it will happen but I'd be afraid of a dependency on imo rather obscure logical symbol precedence rules

Comment: @user3482749 it looks like it's easy to make a formula have only one interpretation with no free variables in this way, but with the usual rules of first order logic,  where I think free variables are permitted, we need parentheses.

Comment: I'd certainly only write that in a formal system. When writing not in such a system, I'd just write it in words, because there's no actual benefit to compressing it down to a less-readable mass of symbols.